# android source code building

Tags: android, git, android-source, android-build

I have already the complete source code of android 4.0. How can I bring it to git so that I can compile and build it through ubuntu 14.04 LTS? Actually I want to build custom ROM.

Is there any other way of compiling and building it?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to put android source code to git, in order to build it. AOSP is a set of projects (hundreds) which already are in their own repos, at github or other hosts.

You should follow build instructions for your AOSP ROM. For example here it is for CyanogenMod built for Samsung Galaxy S4 mini LTE (serranoltexx) 
https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_serranoltexx

If you'll be customizing a ROM and you want to put your changes to git, I think it would be right to fork changed repos and modify your repo manifest to use the forked repos.

Comment: actually i already have a source code i don't want to download the source again

Comment: If you already have AOSP source code locally you can try to start building it as described here: https://source.android.com/source/building-running.html You may need to check if necessary tools installed https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

Comment: when i built it. it gives me permission denied error for some files. How to solve this issue?  I have tried all the methods i found on the google. I also have installed all the requiered components

Comment: /bin/bash: prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Permission denied
/bin/bash: prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Permission denied
/bin/bash: prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Permission denied

Comment: /bin/bash: build/core/find-jdk-tools-jar.sh: Permission denied
build/core/config.mk:268: *** Error: could not find jdk tools.jar, please install JDK6, which you can download from java.sun.com.  Stop
** Don't have a product spec for: 'full'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?